# Can Authentication Details be added to a Windows Azure Scheduler Job?

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I'm going to be creating a Windows Azure Scheduler Job that will make a RESTful `POST` call to a resource on interval. This part is easy, except the fact that the URI is secured and requires `Basic Authentication` credentials.

Using the Azure Management Portal (or see via: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495651.aspx) I don't see anywhere to add `Basic Authentication` credentials or even custom header values.

Is it possible to add credentials to a configured Azure Scheduled Job `HTTP/HTTPS` call, or will the scheduler not handle this ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does support Basic Auth.  After creation navigate to the "jobs", click on the job that you want add basic auth.  There are 2 text boxes to enter username and password.

[image]

Comment: How are the basic credentials set up on the service itself? Is that the auth in IIS? If yes, how do we set it up for an MVC action method, which is part of a website (azure webapp)?